# Ceros a la izquierda cuando exporto datagridview a excel en C#

Tags: c#, excel

Como verán, cuando exporto los datos del datagridview a excel, no se pasan los ceros a la izquierda de los números y necesito que sí aparezcan.

```
public void ExportarExcel2(DataGridView dgv)
{
      try
            {
                SaveFileDialog archivo = new SaveFileDialog();
                archivo.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
                archivo.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy.H-m-ss");
                if (archivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libroDeExcel = aplication.Workbooks.Add();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hojaDeExcel = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libroDeExcel.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

         

                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "A"] = dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "B"] = dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "C"] = dgv.Columns[2].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "D"] = dgv.Columns[3].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "E"] = dgv.Columns[4].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "F"] = dgv.Columns[5].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells[1, "G"] = dgv.Columns[6].HeaderText;
                    

                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[1].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[2].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[3].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[4].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[5].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeExcel.Columns[6].AutoFit();                            
                    hojaDeExcel.Name = "Reporte Actualizado";

                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                            {
                                hojaDeExcel.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    hojaDeExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    libroDeExcel.SaveAs(archivo.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                    libroDeExcel.Close(true);
                    aplication.Quit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Reporte Exportado a Excel");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al exportar la información debido a: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Excel presupone que son numeros.. seguro alguien sabra decirte como decirle a excel que no son numeros...

Comment: Prueba con `hojaDeExcel.Cells.NumberFormat = "Text";` en la línea inmediatamente anterior a `libroDeExcel.SaveAs` eso debería cambiar el formato de todas las celdas de la hoja a Texto, ya que en excel si no se especifica el formato el formatea como número lo que parece número